# Run an SQLite command and quit?

Tags: sqlite

If I run something like this:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite -cmd 'UPDATE users SET update_time = 0;'
```

It's going to successfully run the command, however it's also going to open the sqlite command line interface. Is it possible to make it run the command and then close afterwards? I've tried adding `.quit` at the end of my command:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite -cmd 'UPDATE users SET update_time = 0; .quit'
```

but it says "command invalid" so I guess it's expecting actual SQL queries only.

Any idea if it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the CLI active is what the `-cmd` option does.

To execute some command and quit, don't use this option:

```
sqlite3 mydb.sqlite 'UPDATE users SET update_time = 0;'
```